# Removing duplicate typedef's

Tags: c++

I have code duplicated in the following program. I need to move `using VectorPtr = std::vector<T>*` out of both `foo` classes. I need to use private `ptr` as a return pointer from `getVal` method. How can I move the alias out of the classes ?

```
enum ENUM
{
    E1,
    E2
};

template<ENUM e, class T> struct foo;
template<class T>
class foo<ENUM::E1, T>
{
public: 
    using VectorPtr = std::vector<T>*;
    static VectorPtr getVal() { return ptr; }   
private:    
    static VectorPtr ptr;
};

template<class T>
class foo<ENUM::E2, T>
{
public:
    using VectorPtr = std::vector<T>*;
    static VectorPtr getVal() { return ptr; }
private:
    static VectorPtr ptr;
};
```

Comment: Aliasing a pointer type just to keep using it as a pointer is bad bad bad. In C++ `Ptr` is spelled `*`. Better get used to it.

Comment: Define "move the alias out of classes". If you want to declare the alias globally, just do it. `template<typename T> using VectorPtr=std::vector<T> *`, and reference it from both classes simply as `VectorPtr<T>`.

Comment: use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to review your code

Comment: @StoryTeller Why is that ?

Comment: @Blackcowgirl - Yes, the handles are pointers. But they aren't intended to be **used** as pointers. They are an abstraction. Microsoft could change it tomorrow into `long int`, and no code that followed the abstraction will break. Once you start clocking experience you'll see the bugs pile up with your approach. In particular, you'll be surprised by what a "const pointer" is for `std::vector<T>*` vs your `VectorPtr`.

Comment: The entire content of the two specialisations is duplicate. Why have them in the first place? (And raw pointers, and pointers to `std::vector`, and static data). Oh and you [can't refefine a struct into a class](https://godbolt.org/g/4hHykW).

Comment: @n.m. - You may, it's a Clang warning elevated to an error because of Werror

Comment: @StoryTeller This is a rather poor suggestion. Not only it goes against common practices adopted in  stdlib and in swarm of other libraries, but it actually makes many things impossible (or really complicated). For example instantiating pointer types inplace `foo(std::vector<T>*{});`. I can image all the suffering you must be going through when redeclaring function pointers every time or modifying pointer types spreaded around the code...

Comment: @VTT - Oh yes, it's such a fantastic thing that the standard library has to define two aliases a pop every time because the "duh" way of being const correct just doesn't work. At least it's tolerable there because the library's aim is abstraction and not syntactic sugar. As for instantiating in place, that's hardly a call for an alias with an over-reaching scope. A sane proposal to allow parentheses that resolve such issues would be nice. And if I'm not relying on deduction, I prefer nullptr anyway. And don't worry about my code bases, I myself try to design well in advance.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would rather call such proposal insane considering how messy C++ language syntax already is. As for design... The sign of good design is an ability to adopt to inevitable changes. And without using aliases to pointer types code can not have such ability. Basically not using aliases for pointer types is nothing but a code smell, the same flavor as not using aliases for non-pointer types and copypasting the same declarations over and over again.

Comment: @VTT - I'd say the sign of good design is not to to require widespread cascading modifications as a response to change. A sugary type alias just masks how bad the design failed. But you are of course are entitled to your own views, even the idiosyncratic ones.

Comment: Thank you @StoryTeller, I like your answers very much. They are "been there done that" kind of things in C++.

Comment: @Blackcowgirl - You are very kind :) But be sure not to take my comments as dogma. Type aliases are fine when they abstract something. Just be sure it is indeed an abstraction, and not an attempt at syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to template the `using`

```
template<class T>
using VectorPtr = std::vector<T>*;

template<ENUM e, class T> struct foo {
public:
    static VectorPtr<T> getVal() { return ptr; }
private:
    static VectorPtr<T> ptr;
};
```

**Or** (using same templated `using`):

```
template<ENUM e, class T> struct foo;
template<class T>
class foo<ENUM::E1, T> {
public:
    static VectorPtr<T> getVal() { return ptr; }
private:
    static VectorPtr<T> ptr;
};

template<class T>
class foo<ENUM::E2, T> {
public:
    static VectorPtr<T> getVal() { return ptr; }
private:
    static VectorPtr<T> ptr;
};
```

Comment: =]] Thanks Bo, could you tell me how to move the `ptr` out as a commonality then have it shared with all `foo`'s, and at the same time you will have to keep its type dependent up on `T` ?